# Apple Instruments - Reference Counting

Tags: instruments

I'm having trouble understanding what's happening here. I am debugging an app because I think it's retaining a class 'DownloadController' after its been used. Using ARC, it should automatically release the object when the Reference Count is zero.

So in instruments it looks like

[image: Live]

From that I assume, that 48 bytes have are still 'live' and being used, correct?

So I try to find what is causing this object to be retained, when its no longer needed, by using reference count traces.

[image: Ref Cnt]

At the bottom it says, RefCt is zero; so why has the object not been released? How can I debug further, why it hasn't been released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These ARC anomilies were being caused by NSZombieEnabled, after removing this argument it started freeing objects.